# How to get list of openstack Instances with Project name

Tags: command-line-interface, openstack, openstack-nova

My openstack setup is Mitaka version.

I want to list all the Instances with Project Name.

I tried with below command but it shows Tenant ID but not name.

```
nova list --all-tenants
```

Answer (score 8):

The command to list all instances of a project is:

```
openstack server list --all-projects --project $projectname
```

The parameter `--all-projects` is needed to list instances that don't belong to the current project.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to include projects' names to 'server list' output, so you can just use 'project list' before.

```
for PROJECT in `openstack project list -c=Name -f=value` ; do echo "$PROJECT" >> server.csv ; openstack server list -c=Name -c=Networks -c=Flavor --status=Active --project $PROJECT --all -f=csv >> server.csv ; done
```

(--all is the same as --all-projects here)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of servers per project in CSV format,

This one liner gets the list of projects, than for each project it queries the instances.

```
openstack project list -f value| awk '{print "echo "$2";openstack server list --all --all-projects --long  -c ID -c Name -c Host -f csv --project "$2 }' | xargs -0 -n1 sh -c
```